# Resizing NTFS partition on USB drive

Tags: gparted

I am trying to make an external backup and wanted to make a partition on my external USB drive for that.

But using gparted, I cannot get this done. I connected the drive, unmounted it, but cannot resize(smaller, not bigger ofc) it although there are like 19GB I could use for an ext4 partition.

And FYI I am using Antergos(Arch).

What am I missing? I don't think this necessarily requires a live linux.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You don't have enough free space... you'll have to delete some things.

Comment: But I want to create free space, not use free space to make the partition bigger.

Comment: No, I mean you don't have free space inside the partition, so you can't shrink it.

Answer (score 0):

I think, [psusi](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169236/resizing-ntfs-partition-on-usb-drive#comment278821_169236) gave you the right hint.

Your partition `/dev/sdc1` is a container that holds an NTFS filesystem. That filesystem in turn is a container that holds the files stored therein.

So if you want to shrink the partition, you have to shrink the filesystem first. If you want to keep all files therein, it is clear that you can shrink it at maximum by the amount of free space in the filesystem, minus some rounding that depends on the filesystem granularity.

I am not familiar with gparted but I guess it does both shrinking steps—transparent for you—in one process.

If you are not daunted by the command line, you can use the program `ntfsresize` to check whether your NTFS partition is shrinkable at all

```
ntfsresize --check /dev/sdc1
```

and by what maximum amount

```
ntfsresize --info /dev/sdc1
```

The latter command gives you a bunch of additional information including the space that is used by the contents of the filesystem (files) and that is therefore not available for shrinking, and the minimum size of the filesystem that you can shrink it to.

Depending on the distribution you find this program in the `ntfsprogs` or `ntfs-3g` package—the latter applies to the current [Arch distribution](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/ntfs-3g).

Both commands have to be issued with sufficient privileges, thus typically using `sudo` or, if necessary, as root (be careful here).

If it turns out that you can shrink, but not far enough, follow [psusi's advice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169236/resizing-ntfs-partition-on-usb-drive#comment278821_169236) and move some files out of the NTFS filesystem to free a sufficient amount of space there.

If you are familiar with gparted, I recommend to stick to it for the actual shrinking—albeit you could do this also from the command line using the NTFS utilities in the package named above and `fdisk` or `gdisk` as appropriate.

But whatever way you choose, your first two steps should always be

1. Have a backup of the whole disk—a disk image would be best.
2. Verify that backup (image) against the disk.

Good luck.